# How can I override `distributionManagement` of module POM in a reactor POM?

Tags: maven, deployment, maven-reactor

I have a maven project which is basically a reactor pom around several other standalone projects.

- Root

  - module1

    - submodule1
    - submodule2
  - module2

    - submodule3
    - submodule4

The `submoduleX` modules inherit from various parent POMS (e.g. `submodule1` has a different parent than `submodule2`) and are out of my control. However I want to deploy the artifacts of my project to some repository. So in my root reactor pom I specified some `<distributionManagement>` setting, where the repositories for the artifacts are configured.

However when running `mvn deploy` on the reactor POM, the sub modules try to deploy their artifacts to the repositories inherited from their parent poms instead of the one's specified in the root reactor pom. Is there some way of overriding this from the root reactor pom or am I out of luck here?

Comment: Not sure I understand how, for example `submodule1` has multiple parents. One project can only have a single parent.

Comment: My description was somewhat misleading. I meant that `submodule1` has a different parent than `submodule2`, etc, not that they have multiple parents.

Answer (score 1):

You may specify the parameters of the repository you want to deploy to, if you are using the [`mvn deploy:deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal of the maven-deploy-plugin to deploy them to your repository.

As suspected, `mvn deploy:deploy` will not work in your case, since you cannot properly control the `distributionManagement` section of your poms without having access to their parent poms. The reactor pom is not enough for this.